# MySQL Shopping Cart Structure

Tags: mysql, schema, e-commerce

I am looking to create a MySQL shop that is capable of handling multiple categories. I have all of the category facility etc sorted but the bit I am not getting anywhere with is this..

Each item can have multiple options, for example a T-Shirt should have the options 'Colour' and 'Size'. I then need to create a number of variations/ derived products from the parent product specifying that an Extra Large Blue T-Shirt has 20 in stock (for example). The problem is, it's not just clothes being sold, it could be any number of things. So I also need this schema to be able to handle an infinite number of variants such as '**6mm**' '**Large**' Birthday Card with '**Sports Car**' design. 6mm, Large, and 'Ace' being the variables. This way I am able to ensure that we do not have any stock control issues. If it is any use to you, below is my current site structure.

[Existing Database Schema http://www.hallwaystudios.com/screenshots/uploads/g5B7SNKU.png](http://www.hallwaystudios.com/screenshots/uploads/g5B7SNKU.png)

I hope you understand what I mean and that someone has an answer to my problem! Many thanks in advance (and after of-course)

Comment: You don't have a question mark... What is your question?

Comment: Why reinvent e-commerce?  There are several ready-made solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not too sure what the problem is here... I'd probably create four tables:

```
-- a table of item types (t-shirt, birthday card, etc.)
CREATE TABLE ItemTypes (
  TypeID      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  TypeName    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

-- a table of associated properties
CREATE TABLE TypeProperties (
  PropertyID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  TypeID      INT NOT NULL,
  PropName    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  INDEX(Property, TypeID),
  FOREIGN KEY(TypeID) REFERENCES ItemTypes(TypeID)
);

-- a table of specific items (XL Blue t-shirt, large bday card w/sports car, etc.)
CREATE TABLE Items (
  ItemID      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  TypeID      INT NOT NULL,
  ItemName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ItemPrice   DECIMAL UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ItemStock   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  INDEX(ItemID, TypeID),
  FOREIGN KEY(TypeID) REFERENCES ItemTypes(TypeID)
);

-- the dictionary of property values
CREATE TABLE ItemProperties (
  ItemID      INT NOT NULL,
  TypeID      INT NOT NULL,
  PropertyID  INT NOT NULL,
  Value       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ItemID, Property),
  INDEX(ItemID,     TypeID),
  INDEX(PropertyID, TypeID),
  FOREIGN KEY(            TypeID) REFERENCES ItemTypes     (            TypeID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ItemID,     TypeID) REFERENCES Items         (ItemID,     TypeID),
  FOREIGN KEY(PropertyID, TypeID) REFERENCES TypeProperties(PropertyID, TypeID)
);
```

It ought to be fairly obvious, but just in case, the example data would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTypes (TypeID, TypeName) VALUES
  (1, 'T-Shirt'      ),
  (2, 'Birthday Card'),
  (3, 'Balloon'      );

INSERT INTO TypeProperties(PropertyID, TypeID, PropName) VALUES
  (51, 1, 'Colour' ), (52, 1, 'Size'),
  (53, 2, 'Size/mm'), (54, 2, 'Size'), (55, 2, 'Design'),
  (56, 3, 'Colour' );

INSERT INTO Items (ItemID, TypeID, ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemStock) VALUES
  (101, 1, 'Extra Large Blue T-Shirt',                       10.99, 20),
  (102, 2, '6mm Large Birthday Card with Sports Car Design',  2.99, 17),
  (103, 1, 'Extra Large Black T-Shirt',                      10.99,  5),
  (104, 3, 'Pink balloon',                                    0.10, 60);

INSERT INTO ItemProperties (ItemID, TypeID, PropertyID, Value) VALUES
  (101, 1, 51, 'Blue'       ),
  (101, 1, 52, 'Extra Large'),
  (102, 2, 53, '6'          ),
  (102, 2, 54, 'Large'      ),
  (102, 2, 55, 'Sports Car' ),
  (103, 1, 51, 'Black'      ),
  (103, 1, 52, 'Extra Large'),
  (104, 3, 56, 'Pink'       );
```

Comment: Hi eggyal, thanks for your response. While I appreciate your input this is not quite what I am looking for. Basically I want one product in the shop. For example, T-Shirt.

Comment: @Chris: This would enable you do that... you'd put `ItemTypes` in the shop, then when people view such types, you could list all `Items` of that type showing their properties as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! Maybe I am missing something but while this is a solution for some offerings, I cannot see this as a solution for the issue I am experiencing. I hit enter on my prev comment by mistake and left it too long to reply. When a user goes into the item (e.g. T-Shirt), they then need multiple drowdowns. In this case 'Size' and 'Colour'. If they choose to order an XL Black T-Shirt, the stock of XL Black T-Shirts needs to be deducted accordingly. The same would go for any item, for example a Pink Balloon - the product variant being the colour. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: I have made a couple of edits to make my point clearer, but my proposal does exactly what you suggest - you'd list `ItemTypes` as your product range, then within a page for each such type you would show a drop-down for every related record in `TypeProperties`; the values in those drop-downs would be the related values in `ItemProperties`.  Stock levels for each item are stored in the `Items` table (I am showing 20 blue t-shirts and 5 black t-shirts in stock).

Comment: I see where you are coming from now - sorry for my lack of understanding and thank you for this concept! This now proves my original design was going in completely the wrong direction! Many thanks.

Comment: It would seem I have an issue with this schema and cant figure it out - your help would be much appreciated! When viewing an 'ItemType' I am listing out the options, e.g. Small, Medium, Large. Then I am listing out the colours the size is available in. 'Blue,Black'. The problem being, to avoid duplicate sizes or colours, I am filtering the array of values listed out meaning the PropertyID cannot be used, thus I am unable to trace back properly to the original product based on the selected variation - is there a way I can trace back to the Product based on the selected properties?

Comment: @Chris: If the customer wants to see T-Shirt `Items` which are both 'Extra Large' and 'Black', you would query something like `SELECT ItemID FROM ItemProperties i1 JOIN ItemProperties i2 USING (ItemID, TypeID) WHERE TypeID = 1 AND (i1.PropertyID, i1.Value) = (52, 'Extra Large') AND (i2.PropertyID, i2.Value) = (51, 'Black')`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your response - the problem I have with this is that when I list out the variants I end up with two list boxes, one for size and one for colour. If I do not make the size and colour fields unique values only, the list will appear as - Black,Black,Black,Red,Red,Blue depending on what variants I have. So I have made filtered the array to unique values only but in doing that I loose the PropertyID (this is where I am having the issue). The method you have provided above appears to depend on the PropertyID, is that correct?

Comment: @Chris: But each drop-down box lists the options for exactly one `PropertyID`, no?

Comment: I was not storing the value of PropertyID within the ItemProperties for some reason - I believe I missed that on the original schema. The only concern I have with the above query is there may be an infinite amount of options, say for example 10. How would I expand this query to accomodate for 10 options rather than just the two? Many thanks

Comment: @Chris: Use a loop to construct the SQL?

Comment: I have done this and all seems to be working well, once again thank you for your help.