# Storing multiple values for 1 row in a record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Okay I know the title sounds confusing, but here's basically what I'm having trouble with I have this inventory table that looks like this currently:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
productid MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
category VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
subcategory VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
productname VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
pathtoimage VARCHAR(150),
amountinstock SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (productid)
);
```

The app that I'm building has two additional fields being "sizes" and "colours". It's going to be a form that basically an admin on the website will fill out and be able to add new inventory. I need to have it so that they can enter in MULTIPLE sizes and colours for the same product. For example:

**S, M, L, XL**

**White, Black, Blue**

How can I store these multiple values for one record? Sorry if this is ambiguous... I'm trying to explain it as best as I can.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10398545/623041) help at all?

Comment: Hm... I'm trying to keep it less complicated than that. But I see where you're going with that.

Comment: You are confusing products and inventory. A product has categories, descriptions, a name, pictures, and price(s) whether or not it is in inventory.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple.

Add two more tables. 
One called sizes, one called colours.

Table colours:
Color Product_id

table sizes:
Size Product_id

Then it's a simple matter of

```
SELECT `color` FROM `colours` WHERE `product_id`='myproductid';
SELECT `Size` FROM `sizes` WHERE `product_id`='myproductid';
```

And then simply iterate through it.

That's the way to do it.

If you wish to increase complexity but maintanability you make 4 new tables

Colours: Color_ID Color_name Color_sample

Sizes: Size_ID Size_label Size_name Size_alt

Table prod_colors:
Color_ID Product_id qty

table prod_sizes:
Size_ID Product_id qty

Then it's a simple matter of

```
SELECT * FROM `prod_colors` 
    JOIN `Colours` on `Colours`.`Color_id` = `prod_colors`.`Color_id`
WHERE `product_id`='myproductid' AND `qty` > '0';

SELECT `Size` FROM `sizes` 
    JOIN `Sizes` on `Sizes`.`Size_ID` = `prod_sizes`.`Size_ID`
WHERE `product_id`='myproductid' AND `qty` > '0';
```

- ***Edit*** thanks to kolossus for suggesting a quantitiy column

Comment: So these Colours and Sizes tables would reference Inventory -> productid as a foreign key? Should I have a primary key within these two tables or no? This is all going to be 1 form that's submitted...

Comment: The only primary key you extra need is in the base colours and sizes table.

The prod_id and the color_ID and the Size_ID in the tables prod_colors and Prod_sizes all need to be indexes, not primary keys.

Comment: To understand more about this I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: I'm trying to keep it as less complex as I can. Would the first option be sufficient with two extra tables?

Comment: Nope, it may seem "less" complex for you, but database wise you are creating a mess.
With this set up you get to keep control over the flow whilst being able to change color names, descriptions add them at one central place, without being forced to repopulate and iterate the entire database.
This way you'll have to store less data, so the performance hit on your harddrive, memory and CPU is less than if you make your columns bigger.

Comment: The way it works is that mysql keeps the small values in memory and keeps referncing the same memory bit.
Say for example that colours and sizes together take up about 2 kb in total possible per clothing item.
You'll have about 1000 items that means 2000kb = 2 mb in memory, that has to be read, iterated, splitted, joined, sorted == extra cpu time.
Whils if you simply referency that would only amount to 2kb in memory whils is referenced over and over.
It takes less harddrive access time, less memory, less cpu power.

Comment: Not to mention the update mess. What happens if you have to add an extra size? xxl? Then you'd have to update all the items, instead of just adding one extra size to the sizes table and add with one query the xxl  sizes to the right products...
If you'd store it in a string, you'd be worse of with the split, join functions of mysql or php.

Comment: If you want to optimize for storage you actually better to use a single integer column and treat it as a bit array

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that?

Comment: have a size column that is a byte it will give 8 possible sizes treat every bit as indication if item has such size or not

Comment: Nope, se my response to your post above.
The other problem is anyone who'se more experience with databases will look at you with a look of, why on earth...?
1. Keep it maintainable. 2. Keep it insightfull 3. keep it clear to your collegue/replacement
You might know what the comparisant does, but if you get run over by a bus, the person who gets your job won't understand your choices.

Comment: Some times you need extreme optimizations some time you don't

Comment: true, but if you are going to nitpick on bitwise operators, i'd suggest simplly getting a dedicatd server who's up to the task, and otherwise you've done something wrong on the other end.
Just to compare, basic forum software like phpbb responds quick, fast on even "cheap" servers with big payload, and references,joins everything to the max. don't nitpick on a join, just make sure you make the joins by ints and not by strings... Strings really bog things down.

Comment: I worked on systems that needed such type of optimizations because buying a bigger machine was just no feasible.

Comment: Is the product to be custom made? i.e. it is made to specific size and color on request? or it's available in a fixed quantity per color and size? If it's the latter, then you'll run into problems taking stock of your inventory because you've added the quantity column to the product table. I'd advise you keep the qtty attribute on the color and size tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as comma-delimited string in a single column

Comment: Not a good idea. It will almost always end in pain and regret when you need to query single values or `JOIN` against it.

Comment: Keeping it in separate table and using JOIN for every select can  become a huge performance hit

Comment: @MichaelT Not true if you keep your indexes set up properly.
Joins are one real reason why database tables exist, so you can match  join and fetch information quickly.

Comment: @MichaelT With proper indexing, negligible difference, and not nearly as big a hit as having to do string manipulations and multiple LIKE queries to retrieve a single value from a comma-separated list, or ``FIND_IN_SET()` which does multiple string manips.

Comment: JOINS are also a reason why alternatives like document db exist, I not saying that every join is a problem , but I do saw DB performance killed by some simple joins like above.

Comment: On microsoft sql server you can track how much memory is consumed by what.
Simple index comparison: 12 bytes.
String comparison 3kb
Complex string manipulation(split, join etc...) 100kb

That's on a simple table of only 80.000 items. Index compare is done within 1 second, string compare takes 10 seconds, complex string manipulation compare takes up to 60 seconds.

Don't do complicated string things. Try to stick to integer indexes.

Comment: You don't need to do all the complex filtering in DB you can do it in application, but actually now I am thinking is better to store a single int column for sizes and use bitwise comparisons it will be just 4 bytes per row for sizes

Comment: You could do that, but then you'd have to store values in code. Which makes maintainability by normal staff impossible.
As a developper you want to be able to say to the sales staff, here's the interface, here you can edit values for sizes, colours, fabrics, male or femel or shemale or whatever ale,  here you can add products and descriptions.

Store everything in the database, and then give it over to the sales staff to manage.
Don't store stuff in the programming code.

Comment: It depends that is more important , are sizes suppose to be changeable ? I don't think so, but again it depends on a domain logic of the application.

Comment: Have you ever been to a shopping site for clothes? xxs xs s m l xl xxl xxxl, but then you also have 34,36,38,40,42,43 etc.... all those different way for sizes.
If you import things from europe it has different sizes, etc...

Comment: I understand your motivation and logic and think you will be right in most cases but still in some case my approach will be a better solution.